# To show more than one value to single drop down - SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a question regarding to show more than one value to drop down but use only one value as a parameter

My query

```
select custcode, custname from customertable
```

in return i will have two columns.. at SSRS i want a single dropdown which will show me these two data, but once user select a value, it should pass only customer code to parameter, how to do that with SSRS

Comment: Just create another column concatenating both columns then use it as label and set custcode as value. `select custcode + '-' + custname as label, custcode from customertable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters have two properties that are important - the `Value` and the `Label`. The Value is used as the parameter value in things like SQL expressions; the Label is what is displayed in the parameter selection box.

So we need to have two fields returned by our parameter lookup query in Available Values: the `custcode` which is used as the Value field and the concatenation of `custcode` and `custname` for the Label field.

```
select custcode, custcode + ' - ' + custname as Label
from custmertable
```